# Get repeatable json data in Request select_from_ajax

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a repeatable field --and others-- with an ajax select inside. It has an endpoint route. In the controller of the route i do this

$inputs = $request->input('form');

dd($inputs);
It show all form fields that were completed except the repeatable field. Like this

```
6 => array:2 [
    "name" => "payment_method"
    "value" => 1
  ]
  7 => array:2 [
    "name" => "date"
    "value" => "2020-12-17"
  ]
  8 => array:2 [
    "name" => "expiration"
    "value" => "2020-12-31"
  ]
  9 => array:2 [
    "name" => "invoice_lines_data" <------- repeatable field
    "value" => null <---- HERE THE JSON DATA
  ]
```

I want the actual json value of the repeatable field. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is kind of late, but just recently there was a progress on this feature that includes all data when you set `"include_all_form_fields" => true` inside a repeatable field. Please keep an eye on https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/3439. Until then there is no easy solution to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Update `$(element).select2` function of `select2_from_ajax.blade.php` with the following code.

```php
var formSerializeArray = form.serializeArray();

let rowNumber = element.attr('data-row-number');
let selector = element.attr('data-custom-selector');

// if any dependencies have been declared inside repeatable field
// then send those dependencies value with ajax fetch request
for (var i=0; i < $dependencies.length; i++) {
    var $dependency = $dependencies[i];
    //if element does not have a custom-selector attribute we use the name attribute
    if(typeof element.attr('data-custom-selector') != 'undefined') {
        // we get the row number and custom selector from where element is called
        let rowNumber = element.attr('data-row-number');
        let selector = element.attr('data-custom-selector');

        // replace in the custom selector string the corresponding row and dependency name to match
        selector = selector
            .replaceAll('%DEPENDENCY%', $dependency)
            .replaceAll('%ROW%', rowNumber);
        console.log(selector)

        dependency_val = $(selector).val();
        if(dependency_val){
            formSerializeArray.push({name: $dependency, value: dependency_val});
        }
    }
}


return {
    q: params.term, // search term
    page: params.page, // pagination
    form: formSerializeArray
    //form: form.serializeArray() // all other form inputs
};
```